# Loading multiple pictures from directory into multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to load multiple pictures into multiple arrays.
I can access all files in a directory with PIL

```
allfiles = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
imlist = [filename for filename in allfiles if filename[-4:] in [".png", ".PNG"]]
w, h = Image.open(imlist[0]).size
N = len(imlist)
```

But how can I get these into an array called data1, data 2, data 3, automatically without typing in their names?

what i would like to to with the pictures is something like this

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([[1, 2, 33, 4, 33, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 93, 12]])
data2 = np.array([[1, 14, 33, 15, 33, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 93, 23]])
data3 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data4 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data5 = np.array([[67, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data6 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data7 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 51, 93, 34]])
data8 = np.array([[48, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data9 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [93, 30, 31, 32, 93, 38]])
data0 = np.array([[24, 25, 33, 26, 1, 28], [73, 30, 31, 32, 93, 34]])
data = np.dstack((data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data0))
Newimage = np.where(np.all(np.equal(data, data1[..., np.newaxis]), axis=2), data1, np.nan)
print(Newimage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data1, data2, etc. represent your images, you can go straight to your `dstack`ed array with a list comprehension:

```
data = np.dstack([Image.open(image) for image in imlist])
```

The following line (`Newimage = ...`) should then be possible by reference to the new 3D array only (since each data1, data2, data3 etc. are just slices of this array)